# MySQL column AS with BETWEEN causes error

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I have an issue where I need to AS a column in a MySQL query and execute a BETWEEN on that column. The simplest version I can come up with that illustrates the problem is this:

```
SELECT ID AS post_id FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20)
```

This throws the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'post_id' in 'where clause'
```

Is there a way to make the newly created `post_id` column visible to the BETWEEN operator?

**UPDATE:**

This is my actual query. As you can see, it is slightly more complicated:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key='store_lng' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END ) AS lng,
MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key='store_lat' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END ) AS lat
FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON (wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE
(lng BETWEEN 150.29793837662 AND 152.1161201948)
AND 
(lat BETWEEN -34.775666623377 AND -32.957484805195) 
AND
wp_posts.post_status='publish'
AND
wp_posts.post_type='store'
GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `ID` is a placeholder for some big ugly computation so you can't do a simple `ID BETWEEN 10 AND 20`, right?

Comment: LOL. Ugly, yes. It's Wordpress's main id column name in it's posts table... No placeholder :)

Comment: I tried your query against my own installation of WordPress and it seems to be working great. Is that the query where `post_id` is causing you problems? I don't see it in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Francois; Thanks. Yes the update of the question has my actual query. If I run this I get the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'lng' in 'where clause'

Comment: I know you've already accepted an answer but I wanted to add one where you're not using a sub-query such as the one you've accepted. The `HAVING` clause would be perfect here. Look at my most recent example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> It is not permissible to refer to a
>   column alias in a WHERE clause,
>   because the column value might not yet
>   be determined when the WHERE clause is
>   executed.

You'll either have to use `ID` instead of `post_id` in the `WHERE` clause or use a `HAVING` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT ID AS post_id FROM wp_posts WHERE ID BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

**Update**: Based on your most recent update, you could use a subquery as already suggested or as I suggested earlier, you could use a `HAVING` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT    wp_postmeta.post_id,
          MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'store_lng' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) AS lng,
          MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'store_lat' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) AS lat
FROM      wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON        wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE     wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
          wp_posts.post_type = 'store'
GROUP BY  wp_postmeta.post_id
HAVING    lng BETWEEN 150.29793837662 AND 152.1161201948 AND 
          lat BETWEEN -34.775666623377 AND -32.957484805195
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Your query is very elegant. If I could except two answers I would. Thanks for your help. It's much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using your query after all so it's only fair to accept it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.

This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. 
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: I see. Would there be a way around it? Maybe by using a sub-query or something? If so, I'm kinda stuck on the correct syntax.

Comment: @Luke: Yes, you can use subquery as Bohemian's answer. Or just use `WHERE ID BETWEEN 10 AND 20` as Francois answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question with the "real" query I'm working on. I'm definitely no SQL guru and I would appreciate any help you give getting the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can!

```
SELECT post_id
from (select id AS post_id FROM wp_posts) x
WHERE post_id BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Edited to include changes to question. Try this (haven't run in mysql, but should be close if not correct):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
  wp_postmeta.post_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key='store_lng' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END ) AS lng,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key='store_lat' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END ) AS lat 
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
) x
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = x.post_id
WHERE lng BETWEEN 150.29793837662 AND 152.1161201948
AND lat BETWEEN -34.775666623377 AND -32.957484805195
AND wp_posts.post_status='publish'
AND wp_posts.post_type='store'
```

Comment: Interesting. I've updated my question with the real query I'm working on. Is it possible to apply your solution in my extended query as well. I'm no SQL guru and I need some help on getting the syntax right. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! However, its throwing the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_postmeta GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id ) x LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts' at line 6

Comment: There was a syntax error in your "excellent" query. Thanks for your help!